# ruby: How to remove a hash if one key's value is 0 in an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

For example,I have an array like this:

```
array = [{"a"=>0, "b"=>1, "c"=>2}, {"a"=>2, "b"=>1, "c"=>0}, {"a"=>3, "b"=>1, "c"=>2}]
```

Now I want to remove the item if `"a" == 0`, return to:

```
array = [{"a"=>2, "b"=>1, "c"=>0}, {"a"=>3, "b"=>1, "c"=>2}]
```

How to do?

Comment: To remove elements for which one or more values are zero (i.e., not just for the key `"a"`): `array.reject { |h| h.values.include?(0) } => [{"a"=>3, "b"=>1, "c"=>2}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array#reject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-reject):

```
array.reject { |h| h["a"] == 0 }
#=> [{"a"=>2, "b"=>1, "c"=>0}, {"a"=>3, "b"=>1, "c"=>2}]
```

Comment: Thank you for so fast answer and edited my question more clearly:-)

Answer (score 2):

```
array.collect {|k| k unless k["a"] == 0}.compact
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include an explanation of your code? It helps the reader more than you might think.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `Array#delete_if`

`array.delete_if {|h| h["a"] == 0}`

Comment: No..It will _mutate_ the original object.